# Как сделать переход между экранами без сторибордов

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, uikit

Я полностью удалил Main.storyboard и не могу понять как можно сделать переход с одного экрана на другой. Нашел код, который работает, допустим его можно вставить в button target

```
if let newViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc_id") {
    present(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

он работает если в сториборде объявить Storyboard ID, но как объявить ID если сторибордов нет, или может это как то по-другому делается, подскажите кто знает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать экземпляр нужного вьюконтроллера

```
let newViewController = ViewController()
```

и точно также использовать функции present() и show() для показа нового экрана. Только нужно учесть, что без сториборда вам нужно будет кодом добавлять все UI элементы, @IBOutlet уже работать не будут.

Comment: Ну это понятно что все нужно будет писать кодом, я занимаюсь всего месяц, но насколько я знаю в коммерческой разработке не используют сториборды

Comment: Сториборды зачастую не используют в командной разработке, т.к. при мерже сложно резолвить возникающие конфликты. Но если использовать подход 1 сториборд = 1 экран, то вполне можно.